# Countdown between two defined times?

Tags: java, android

**   I want to build an android application which will count time between two defined times (for example from 12.45 to 21:00. ) How can i do that?**

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

**I have tried in this way. I think I have a fault**

```
f`  Integer year = null;
    Integer monthOfYear = null;
    Integer dayOfMonth = null;
    Integer hourOfDay = null;
    Integer minuteOfHour = null;
    Integer secondOfMinute = null;




      DateTime(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth, hourOfDay, minuteOfHour, secondOfMinute);


      DateTime start = new DateTime(2013, 07, 14, 12, 45, 0);
      DateTime end = new DateTime(2013, 07, 14, 21, 0, 0);

      Seconds diff = Seconds.secondsBetween(start, end);
      mTextField.setText(diff.getSeconds());`
```

**how can i that ?**

Comment: Is your question related to on how to develop android app or how to find the diff. between time?.  Edit the question add the detail

Comment: I don't know what the first lines are supposed to do, but the last four lines work just fine, I have tried them just now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [joda.time library](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) which allows you to subtract times and get the result in seconds.

You would create two [DateTime objects](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) using a constructor that allows you to submit the time with int, like `DateTime(int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth, int hourOfDay, int minuteOfHour, int secondOfMinute, DateTimeZone zone)`.

```
DateTime start = new DateTime(2013, 07, 14, 12, 45, 0, zone);
DateTime end = new DateTime(2013, 07, 14, 21, 0, 0, zone);
```

Then you can use the function for yoda-time [seconds to find the diference](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Seconds.html#secondsBetween%28org.joda.time.ReadableInstant,%20org.joda.time.ReadableInstant%29).

```
Seconds diff = Seconds.secondsBetween(start, end);
```

**Edit:** To show the code in use here an example in a standard Java-Class with a main method:

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.Seconds;


public class Test {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         DateTime start = new DateTime(2013, 07, 14, 12, 45, 0);
          DateTime end = new DateTime(2013, 07, 14, 21, 0, 0);

          Seconds diff = Seconds.secondsBetween(start, end);
          System.out.println(diff.getSeconds());

    }

}
```

Here another example calculating the seconds until the next Christmas

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
     DateTime start = new DateTime();
     DateTime end;
     if(start.getDayOfMonth()>24 && start.getMonthOfYear()==12)
     {
         end = new DateTime(start.getYear()+1, 12, 25, 0, 0, 0);
     }
     else
     {
         end = new DateTime(start.getYear(), 12, 25, 0, 0, 0);
     }
      Seconds diff = Seconds.secondsBetween(start, end);
      System.out.println(diff.getSeconds());

}
```

As has been noted, you can do all this without joda time. In this case you would just use java.util.Date which has a method called getTime() which gives you the timestamp in milliseconds since 1970. If you get the timestamp from two java.util.Date objects (which are of the type long) and subtract them you get the milliseconds between those two dates. Devide this by 1000 to get seconds. Easy but not as Object Oriented as the joda time approach.

In the above case this would be:

```
import java.util.Date;




public class Test {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
     Date start = new Date(2013, 07, 14, 12, 45, 0);
     Date end = new Date(2013, 07, 14, 21, 0, 0);
     System.out.println((end.getTime()-start.getTime())/1000);
}
```

}

However, this java.util.Date constructor is deprecated and should no longer be used. The new way to handle Date is kind of anoying [and is documented here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html).

Comment: No need for external libraries, this can be done without them

Comment: It can be but yodatime is just vastly nicer.

Comment: i have tried in this way `  Integer year = null;
    Integer monthOfYear = null;
    Integer dayOfMonth = null;
    Integer hourOfDay = null;
    Integer minuteOfHour = null;
    Integer secondOfMinute = null;




      DateTime(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth, hourOfDay, minuteOfHour, secondOfMinute);


      DateTime start = new DateTime(2013, 07, 14, 12, 45, 0);
      DateTime end = new DateTime(2013, 07, 14, 21, 0, 0);

      Seconds diff = Seconds.secondsBetween(start, end);
      mTextField.setText(diff.getSeconds());` 
i have get an eror

Comment: You should probably not use null. I will update my answer with a few examples on how to do it.